# How to add new origins to an already existing cloudfront distribution through cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to add an origin to my already existing Cloudfront distribution(created outside of Cloudformation).

Looking at the AWS::CloudFront::DistributionOrigin block in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-origin.html), I could not find any property where I could specify an already existing Cloudfront distribution Id/ARN to add my origin to.

```
AWS::CloudFront::DistributionOrigin
{
  "CustomOriginConfig" : CustomOriginConfig,
  "DomainName" : String,
  "Id" : String, (this is the Origin Id)
  "OriginCustomHeaders" : [ OriginCustomHeader, ... ],
  "OriginPath" : String,
  "S3OriginConfig" : S3OriginConfig
}
```

The console let's me add an origin easily to an already existing distribution and I feel the same should have been possible through Cloudformation. Is there a way I can update my existing Cloudfront distribution with a new origin through Cloudformation ?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is: there's no way. As you can see in documentation [AWS::CloudFront::Distribution Origin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-origin.html) - `Distribution Origin` is **part of [Distribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloudfront-distribution.html)** - it is not standalone resource.

Comment: So it seems like I would need to re-create the cloudfront distribution through cloudformation and then update the origin group array every time I need to add it ? A problem I might have with such an approach is that I have multiple stacks which will need to refer the same cloudfront distribution and add an origin per stack

Comment: Also having this problem my friend. I have a build script for the backend and one for the front end. I need to add the API Gateway origin and CacheBehaviour to my existing Distribution. I wonder if it's possible via AWS SAM.

Comment: @Sigex hey, right now i found a way to add existing ID to CloudFormation template. You can add this as a input parameter and pass this id while updating CF template.

Comment: @Yupik, do you have a code pipeline and codebuild in place for CI/CD. I am attempting to have infrastructure as code for the front and backend which both use the same Cloudfront.

Comment: @Sigex in this case - no. I have few nested stacks in which already declared frontend and backend - with that you can easly access one CloudFront distribution